# Generated HTML reports are empty when running from CI and after sending them through E-Mail (Cypress Mocha Reports)

Tags: html, mocha.js, report, cypress

When I am running my tests locally, then merging and marging my json to html files works fine.
However, when i try to do this from Jenkins CI it  generated a HTML report as an artifact, but i not able to view  the file in chrome after sending the file through mail but i am able to view the content  when i download the file in my local and open it in chrome

stage: test

script:

- npm install
- npx cypress run
- npx mochawesome-merge cypress/reports/mocha/*.json > mochawesome.json
- npx marge mochawesome.json

Expected behavior
A fully loaded HTML file with content of the tests.

versions:
"cypress": "^7.6.0",
"mocha": "^9.2.0",
"mochawesome": "^7.0.1",
"mochawesome-merge": "^4.2.1",
"mochawesome-report-generator": "^6.0.1"